# cf7 calculations and if function

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, contact-form-7, calculation

I'm trying to achieve a simple solution for a calculation problem.
I need to get a specific outcome in the Wordpress-Plugin "Contact Form 7" using this equation `(((values1 * values2)+18) * values3 * values4)`

Overall the equation brings ok results but I needed to update it. The contact form was used to calculate the insurance value from one insurance giver, but now i have to provide a second outcome from a second company in the same form with more variables.

I've tried this.

```
[calculation Calculation-field precision:0 roundup "(((values1 * values2)+18) * values3 * values4)"


"fn_php(

if($_POST{'values1'} == 566 && $_POST{'values2'} == 1 && $_POST{'values4'} == 2) return 400;

if($_POST{'values1'} == 566 && $_POST{'values2'} == 1 && $_POST{'values4'} == 3) return 440;

if($_POST{'values1'} == 566 && $_POST{'values2'} == 1 && $_POST{'values4'} == 4) return 480;

if($_POST{'values1'} == 566 && $_POST{'values2'} == 1 && $_POST{'values4'} == 5) return 520;

if($_POST{'values1'} == 566 && $_POST{'values2'} == 1 && $_POST{'values4'} == 6) return 560;


)"]
```

Obviously it doesnt work.

Thanks in advance and sorry if it's not understandable. I'm almost giving up...

Edit 04.12: Followup on the topic. I've thrown away the idea of making them work together, now I'm trying to get a text outcome in the calculation field. Tried adding a

if($_POST{'values1'} == 566 && $_POST{'values2'} == 0.684) return 'Individual calculation. Contact our agent';

Tried changing return to echo, even print, but no results. I guess the plugin has some limitations or I'm doing something terribly wrong.

I'm using the PVB Contact Form 7 Calculator Add-on.

Comment: As `$_POST` is an array, you should be using square brackets - `$_POST['values1']`

Comment: Square brackets doesn't work in junction with the Contact Form7 calculator, in which i've tried to construct a working calculation form. I've been told that  these {} work the same as these [].

Comment: @Piogor You tagged this as PHP. If it is wordpress or etc, then tag it appropriately.

Comment: @Daedalus-ReinstateMonica Its actually php inside the WordPress plugins, I figured its not inaccurate. Thank You for noticing me about my wrong tags anyway.

Comment: @Piogor What you have above doesn't look at all like valid php to me, so if there is some other processor present, you must tag it appropriately.

Comment: @Piogor For instance; no google results from `fn_php` and **contact-forms-7**, or **wordpress**.  If that however was an attempt at calling a function you created, it's an invalid attempt.  The **,** (comma) is used to separate function call params, not the semi-colon.

Comment: @Daedalus-ReinstateMonica the fn_php is used to insert a php function into the contact forms7 calculation plugin and to be honest it works just fine. The only thing I'm having trouble with is using both calculation methods in the same contact form. I can't get it to work. I can't also tag this post "contact forms7" because I'm a new user and don't have enough reputation. I'm a total newb at anything WordPress and PHP alike.

Comment: @Piogor I added it for you; always check the suggested tags as you type in the tag name.

Comment: @Daedalus-ReinstateMonica Thanks!

Comment: Followup on the topic. I've thrown away the idea of making them work together, now I'm trying to get a text outcome in the calculation field.

Tried adding a if($_POST{'values1'} == 566 && $_POST{'values2'} == 0.684) return 'Individual calculation. Contact our agent';

Tried changing return to echo aswell but no results. I guess the plugin has some limitations or I'm doing something terribly wrong.